# Proper way configuration keys in gradle properties

Tags: android, gradle

Im trying to upload my apk to the playstore direct with android studio.

Using ribot boilerplate I can see that they are putting the keys in gradle.properties like this:

```
ribotAppKeystoreReleaseLocation = keystore/release.keystore
ribotAppReleaseKeyAlias = UNDEFINED
ribotAppReleaseStorePassword = UNDEFINED
ribotAppReleaseKeyPassword = UNDEFINED
```

and in build gradle:

```
    // You must set up an environment var before release signing
    // Run: export RIBOT_APP_KEY={password}
    release {
        storeFile file("${ribotAppKeystoreReleaseLocation}")
        keyAlias "${ribotAppReleaseKeyAlias}"
        storePassword "${ribotAppReleaseStorePassword}"
        keyPassword "${ribotAppReleaseKeyPassword}"
    }
```

If I write my keys in gradle.properties like:

```
ribotAppReleaseStorePassword = THISISMYKEY
```

Im going to have a problem uploading it to git, cause all the team will see this keys.
So, Can I set a system enviroment variable here? Or what should I do?

[See full boilerplate](https://github.com/ribot/ribot-app-android)

Comment: There is no requirement to put `gradle.properties` into version control. There may be for your particular project, in which case you would need to either move these values into a separate properties file or do something else. System environment variables work with Gradle, though not with Android Studio, last I checked.

Comment: @CommonsWare local.properties is in the gitignore but not gradle.properties, Can I set the variables in the local file or I need to add the gradle.properties in gitgnore?

Comment: "local.properties is in the gitignore but not gradle.properties" -- you can add it to `.gitignore` easily enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I set the variables in the local file

Sure:

```
apply plugin 'com.android.application'

def keystorePropertiesFile = file('keystore.properties')
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName '0.0.1'
  }

  signingConfigs {
    release {
      keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
      keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
      storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
      storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I have a separate `keystore.properties` file that I use for the signing information. Then, put `keystore.properties` in `.gitignore`.